# JavaScript intellisense inside webpack file

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, intellisense, webpack

In VS2015 I use JS intellisense through `_references` file or `/// <reference path="source.js" />` notation.
It working great and I like it.

But I want use webpack library together intellisense and it seems there is conflict between these.

For example:

```
// This is some js file whith my code

/// <reference path="react.js" />

var React = require('react');
```

And now, I want code some stuff(create new  React component), but intellisense for library(React) doesn't work, because local variable React overides intellisense (I think).

Is there some solution how to fix this issue?